# VS Code tool tip hint doesn't show comments

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, comments

I have written comment for my function in typescript and I want to see comments everywhere this function has been used. But for this code:

```js
/** Checks localStorage for "lang".
 *  Returns "fa" if not specified.
 */

export const getAppLanguages = () => {
  const value = window.localStorage.getItem("lang");
  if (value === "fa") return "fa";
  if (value === "en") return "en";
  window.localStorage.setItem("lang", "fa");
  return "fa";
};
```

when I hover over the function in the same file it declared, the hint includes the comment:
[tool tip with comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaxoT.png)

but in other files that I have used this function It doesn't show comments for example for following code:

```js
const initialState: initialLanguageStateType = {
  appLanguage:
    (getAppLanguages() as AppLanguageEnum.fa | AppLanguageEnum.en) ||
    AppLanguageEnum.fa,
};
```

I encountered:

[tool tip without comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsxXQ.png)

I tried to add some config in vscode settings.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue in my [mre]. please actually give a [mre] (emphasis on "minimal") that I can try. Include version info for your VS Code and the tsconfig as well.